# iptables block all inbound and outbound traffic except for my IPs

Tags: iptables

Previously I asked how to block all traffic except for specific IPs however that wasn't enough. I need to block all outbound/inbound except for my IPs. I don't want to be able to ping/connect to any IP not listed.

This is what I used before

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 1.1.1.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP    # or REJECT
service iptables save
service iptables restart
```

How can I stop all the outbound traffic except for 1.1.1.1 also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 1.1.1.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 1.1.1.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
service iptables save
service iptables restart
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete line #2 and add the following lines:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT \! -s  1.1.1.1 -j REJECT
iptables -A FORWARD \! -s  1.1.1.1 -j REJECT
```

Comment: That lost me connection to the server. Should there be double space after -s?

Comment: So it's work fine.... No single space or double space no differ.

Comment: It doesn't work fine 1.1.1.1 should be able to communicate with the server

Comment: I'm confusing, Do you want to 1.1.1.1 access to net or not?

Comment: test with above changes (\!)

Comment: Yes I want 1.1.1.1 to have access. That's my IP, I still need to be able to connect through SSH (I don't want to use port ranges though). I still drop access to the server right after entering those

Comment: So abobe rules block all traffick except from 1.1.1.1